# Android Studio automatically erases my static imports in Unit tests

Tags: android-studio-2.0, android-studio-import

Android Studio automatically erases my static imports. I started out creating new tests using robolectric and when I used static import for `import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;` Android-Studio automatically removes it. this is so frustrating.

Is there some settings I need to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences --> Editor --> Code Style --> Java, select "Imports" tab.

You can manage imports there as you see fit.
For example, I have some settings in the section "Packages to Use Import with '*'".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrZMu.png)